# Warning : The page index.html ran insecure content

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, dojo

I deployed my application on google appe engine. My web site use Dojo with the template claro. When I run "google chrome inspection", I see a lot of warning when I navigate throught my site. Here is the type of warnings :

```
The page index.html ran insecure content from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css.
The page index.html ran insecure content from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js.
```

Do I need to configurate something in the appengine-web.xml or web.xml?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If your page is always accessed by secure url (https) then you might try accessing the secure versions of those include files.  I think you can just use https: in place of http: in the url for those two files.

If you want to get fancy, you can check to see if the page is secure and pick either the secure or non-secure version of the link.  I can post a sample of that if you need it.

Addendum: To save people time, I am posting @mercator's superior solution here:

> No need to get fancy. If you want to pick the secure or non-secure version depending on whether your own site is secure, you can use a protocol-relative link. E.g. //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js

Comment: No need to get fancy. If you want to pick the secure or non-secure version depending on whether your own site is secure, you can use a protocol-relative link. E.g. `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js`.

Comment: @mercator, you really should write yours as an answer. I found this more than two years later and your answer is the most relavent/helpful

Comment: @mercator Change your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

what if the site doesn't support https?? For instance, I'm sending the request to world bank, which only supports http?

EDIT:  on chrome, click the "shield" icon on the right of the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Inspection validates only client side code, not server side. So, server configuration in `appengine-web.xml`/`web.xml` doesn't matter here.

At this case it says that your html is using some external code, from other sites, that can be insecure. It not a big problem, btw. But if you wish, you can copy this files (`claro.css` and `dojo.xd.js`) to your own site to fix this issue.