# ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: google-maps

I use google map's api in my website to show couple of locations. Google Maps is working just fine in my local solution but not in my website. I changed this source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false"> </script>
```

to this one. and i again changed this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
```

with this one...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
```

Only thing it says: **ReferenceError: google is not defined**

Does anyone familiar with such problem?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Owing to the fact that my website uses **https** for the connection, I can not use http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false. When I debug the whole page, this link says: Warning : **The page index.html ran insecure content**. so I made another search on google and came across to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309013/warning-the-page-index-html-ran-insecure-content). so what basically causes a problem is not using https link in the source part so the correct link will be (for me)

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

now everything works just fine!

Comment: @ParthChavda, try using //maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

Answer (score 14):

That's an old URL. If you look at the [**examples from the documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/), almost all of them use:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: I changed the source like you said, but I still receive the same error :/

Comment: Are you able to load it directly in the browser, for example if you click here? : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false Does your server run behind a firewall?

Comment: I just noticed that in Google Chrome's Javascript console: it gives the following error: [blocked] The page at https://www.mypage.com/GoogleMapPage.aspx ran insecure content from http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&sensor=false.

Comment: and yes Marcelo, I am able to load it.

Comment: my links were fine. http -> https problem.
[source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309013/warning-the-page-index-html-ran-insecure-content)

Comment: This works, but the sensor query param has now been deprecated. This link could simplify to //maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js.

Answer (score 8):

To me, with the new Google Maps API, simply this solution worked:
Just omit "async defer" from the script provided by goolge:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={your_key}"></script>
```

TO

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={your_key}"></script>
```

Comment: your answer is correct but there should be some other work around. like instead of using `document.ready`, can we check for `google` variable to be check if ready.

Answer (score 1):

i met this problem in the rails application.

request to googlemap was from http and https pages

and it solved:

```
= javascript_include_tag "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
```

if protocol not defined rails inserts automatic

Answer (score 0):

The new google maps API uses async to load the google maps api to prevent the page from loading slow, you can see in the documentation that they have a `callback` parameter, this parameter is the function name defined in your javasscript that will be called once the google maps api has been loaded in the browser, so if you have a function called `initMap()` you will amend this function to `callback=initMap` for example:

```
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**YOUR_API_KEY**callback=initMap">
```

then in your javascript file you will define the `initMap` function as follows:

```
async function initMap() {
const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
});}
```

Please note the `async` modifier at the start of the function. I have noticed in the example they added initMap for some reason to the javascript function, this should **not** be included in the javascript file, but rather in the `callback` parameter.