# AngularJS data-binding not working on iOS Safari Only for Heroku App

Tags: ios, angularjs, heroku, data-binding, mobile-safari

In my current MEAN stack project, everything functions fine on desktop Safari, Chrome, and mobile Chrome, but in mobile Safari for iOS, data-binding shows as text (e.g. `{{data.total}}` as opposed to `$25`). To make matters worse, when I open the app from iOS Safari served from localhost, it also works properly.

I've tried rolling back my Heroku app and the problem persists, even when I go back to a version from when I'm sure it looked good on an iPhone. I've checked it out on others' iPhones, and gotten the same negative result. I can't find this problem elsewhere on the internet, nor am I sure what I should be looking for as the problem seems to be with Heroku or iOS.

Here's the live page: http://minneapolish3-beta.herokuapp.com/reddress. This has me very much stumped, but I'm pretty green. If you find it not working on other platforms, I'd love to know about that as well.

(Naturally, I can't well spin up a CodePen example as the problem is only occurring in the wild.)

Answer (score 1):

A friend introduced me to the [Safari Web Inspector for mobile](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787) which allwed me to see warnings, alerts, etc.

It turns out that my Google Maps API call, via http://, was causing the page to break on mobile Safari. When I changed it to https:// everything worked! Thanks go to [Bonus Kun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218067/bonus-kun) whose [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249136/referenceerror-google-is-not-defined) helped expedite my solution.