# ReferenceError: google is not defined (Google Maps)

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, referenceerror

hope you can help me again... the print screen (on link below) shows what happens when run my app on Genymotion emulator (ionic run android -cls). I don't if it's important, but before that I was getting the MultiDex Error and I solved it when I updated my jdk from 1.7 to 1.8. Now my problem is that "google is not defined", however on my index I already have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://mts0.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es"></script>
```

Considering that this error shows something wrong with the ionic.bundle.js file I think I need to take a look at this file, but I'm a beginner on ionic development and I don't know what to look for on this file.

Someone can help me to understand what do I have to do to solve this issue?

PS: I'm not allowed to use pictures on my posts yet, so this link have the same post with the print sreen of the situation: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/referenceerror-google-is-not-defined/58356

Comment: Check this SO question [14229695](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229695/google-maps-api-throws-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-only-whe) and [12249136](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249136/referenceerror-google-is-not-defined) if it can help you.

Comment: I checked those posts before, but they didn't help me. Thanks for your help, but I still have problem... do you have some other suggestion, or the solution itself?

Answer (score 1):

to the knowledge of all, I solved this error. On my index page I had "https//":

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es"></script>
```

to solve it, I just changed to "http://":

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es"></script>
```

Comment: hide your api key