# jQuery is not Runnig

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloud9-ide

I am working on [this code](https://c9.io/behseini/daycare/workspace/layout.html). Why is the jQuery not working here?

I am running the page on Cloud9 IDE online editor and this the code I have before `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
          alert("This is a Test Message");
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Here is the list of error on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js:29
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined layout.html:48**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your

```
<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To

`https://` instead of `http://`

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the warning in your browser you'll see the reason why.
The problem is it refuses completely to load your jquery.js that cause $ undifined of course.

That's the warning I get :

[blocked] The page at https://c9.io/behseini/daycare/workspace/layout.html ran insecure content from http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js.

With that error I think you can follow that link :

[Warning : The page index.html ran insecure content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309013/warning-the-page-index-html-ran-insecure-content)

Cause of your https, you have to load file on a https
Try with that url maybe : https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Hope that's gonna help you.